# using multipass on macOS, mounted directory is seen empty

Tags: macosx, multipass

I started an ubuntu vm (named k3s) with multipass, I mount a local directory, with :

```
multipass mount ~/Documents/odoo-saas k3s:~/k8S
```

but when in the vm, the directory is seen empty, but if I create a file from the vm i can see it from the macos source directory, but still not when on the vm,
the mounted directory is seen empty inside the vm.

thanks for help to solve this issue.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to successfully mount and shared files from a folder that is not in ~/Documents path. See [this Reddit post](https://www.reddit.com/r/Ubuntu/comments/11x6l1b/multipass_vm_cant_access_shared_folder_mac_m1_host/).

Answer (score -1):

I found the solution, with the help of Bing Copilot, by giving multipass full access to the disk, on the macos...

As I did not managed to restart all the multipass process, so I had to reboot the mac :(..
But now it's OK, I can see the files in the mounted directory, inside the vm !

Comment: giving a random piece of software full access to the disk sounds like a horrible solution..